# How to move users to another voice-channel with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I need a discord bot that moves 10 random users (or less, if there don't are 10) from voice-channel A to voice-channel B and plays a sound-file in channel B then. Can you help me please?
Unfortunately, I get errors, with all codes I tried out.

My code to get the users as a object:

```js
var channelWarten = GUILD.channels.resolve(data.warten);
var channelGehtLos = GUILD.channels.resolve(data.gleichGehtsLos);

channelWarten.members.forEach(mem =>{
    console.log(memb.username);
})
```

The error:

```
const type = Object.keys(ChannelTypes)[data.type];
                                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at new Channel (C:\...\Bot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\structures\Channel.js:16:49)
    at new GuildChannel (C:...\Bot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\structures\GuildChannel.js:28:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:...\Bot\index.js:5:22)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m
```

Comment: And where is the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I forget it

Comment: The first part of my code is:

`var channelWarten = GUILD.channels.resolve(data.warten);
            var channelGehtLos = GUILD.channels.resolve(data.gleichGehtsLos);

            channelWarten.members.forEach(mem =>{
                console.log(memb.username);
            })
`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66470462/edit) your post and include it in your question. Also include the exact error you receive.

Comment: Where is `data` defined?

Comment: data is defined in a JSON-File:

const fs = require('fs');
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json'))

Data I am using in other methods, so it have function.